# Android application crashes when I drop item into gridview

Tags: android, gridview, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drag and drop an item between grid view, and the item is correctly dragged but when the application crashes when in action.

This is my code:

```
 case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                    PassObject passObj = (PassObject)event.getLocalState();
                    View view = passObj.view;
                    Artifact passedItem = passObj.artifact;
                    List<Artifact> srcList = passObj.srcList;
                    AbsListView oldParent = (AbsListView)view.getParent();
                    ArtifactAdapter srcAdapter = (ArtifactAdapter) oldParent.getAdapter();

                    LinearLayoutAbsListView newParent = (LinearLayoutAbsListView)v;
                    ArtifactAdapter destAdapter = (ArtifactAdapter)(newParent.absListView.getAdapter());
                    List<Artifact> destList = destAdapter.getList();

                    if(removeItemToList(srcList, passedItem)){
                        addItemToList(destList, passedItem);
                    }

                    srcAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    destAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    //smooth scroll to bottom
                    newParent.absListView.smoothScrollToPosition(destAdapter.getCount()-1);

                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                default:
                    break;
```

The problem is in this line exactly :

```
ArtifactAdapter destAdapter = (ArtifactAdapter)(newParent.absListView.getAdapter());
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Post your logcat ?

Comment: Whenever you are reporting a crash, don't forget to post your logcat as well, as it makes it easy for others to track the problem.